# Materialize tooltip is not working within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, materialize

My Code is given below . Please check  and reply .
Thanks

```
<div ng-repeat="(x, y) in items">

<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-    tooltip="I am tooltip">Hover me!</a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and everything works fine when I removed the spaces in `data-tooltip` attribute.

```
<a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-    tooltip="I am tooltip">Hover me!</a>

----------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^
```

Comment: Sorry Thats my writing fault .....   Actual Code is-----     <a class="btn tooltipped" data-position="bottom" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="I am tooltip">Hover me!</a>

Comment: The code is working fine here. Have you included materialize files correctly? The buttons are appearing in screen?

Answer (score 0):

Did you initialize the tooltip before your content has been loaded? If so, you should initialize it after the render of `items` data. Otherwise there will be no `.tooltiped` DOM to be initialized.